# Altering CSS in a dynamically generated HTML file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, cheerio

There are about 20 styled articles (5-10 pages each with inconsistent sections) I need to display in my app. Without having to manually write components for each of them, we've started to export HTML from a Google Doc where they're hosted and display in an iframe. While this mostly gets what we need, there's some inconsistent styling and other changes I'd like to address.

I've started writing a JS script (node.js) that will consume all of the HTML files and try to format them correctly but having issues finding a correct library to do this.

I've tried using Jsoup, jsdoc, node-html-parser, and finally landed on cheerio.

What I'm stuck on is targeting dynamically generated classes based on their attributes and changing them. For instance, I'm trying to make changes to the superscripts in the HTML and the only thing I have to go off of is the attribute 'vertical-align'.

```
.c3 {
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Note that the class c3 is dynamically generated so we can't search off of that. But basically I'd want to target it and then change all of the class attributes to something like:

```
 .c3 {
    font-size: 6pt;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.4em;
 }
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to handle something like this? I have to do some more complicated things in the script like target img elements, and modify classes for those elements and their parents. Any library suggestions would be appreciated, because Jquery doesn't seem like the right tool for this.

Note: CSS is inline within the HTML file within  tags

Answer (score 0):

**"Note: CSS is inline within the HTML file within tags"**

Based on that, one way would be to loop through all elements with a style attribute using `querySelectorAll`, and then see if any of those with inline css contain the target style.  You could then remove the inline styles and apply a class.  The more you can narrow the query selector the better this will perform.

- `document.querySelectorAll("[style]");`  all elements with a style attribute.
- `document.querySelectorAll("div[style]");` all div elements with a style attribute.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[style]");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  style = elements[i].getAttribute("style");
  if (style.includes("vertical-align")) {
    console.log( elements[i].getAttribute("style") );    //original
    elements[i].removeAttribute("style");
    elements[i].classList.add("replacementClass");
    console.log( elements[i].getAttribute("style") );    //empty

    // or instead of a class if you want to just update the style
    elements[i].setAttribute('style','font-size: 6pt; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; top: -0.4em;');
    console.log( elements[i].getAttribute("style") );    //inline
  }
}
```

```css
.replacementClass {
  font-size: 6pt;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
}
```

```html
<span id="test" style="vertical-align: super; font-size: 10pt;">oh boy</span>
```

Removing the inline style might be the only way because if the inline css isn't removed it will override any classes you apply to it.  You could end up with quite a few "rules" to apply based on this method though.